# Apache Kafka Microservice in docker

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I'm currently facing challenges managing the connection between two Docker-based microservices using Apache Kafka. When running the microservices without Docker, everything works smoothly. However, when attempting to run the producer and consumer within Docker containers, both fail to connect to the Kafka broker, which is also running in Docker.

Kafka Configuration:

I'm running Kafka inside Docker with the following listeners configuration:

```
listeners = INTERNAL://0.0.0.0:19092,EXTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9092,DOCKER://0.0.0.0:29092
```

Are there additional steps I need to take to ensure a successful connection between microservices within Docker and the Kafka broker within Docker?
Are there any specific configurations or considerations I should be aware of when using Kafka within a Docker environment?
How can I debug or find out more about why the producer and consumer are not connecting?

Comment: You need `advertised.listeners` to be set correctly, not only listeners